# Adding a column after the last column using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have below jQuery code in the bottom of the html document. My purpose is to add a column after the last one based on the html code further below.

The tbody (with id="output") was generated as an output from a jsp file. I've tested it on JSFIDDLE and it works fine but I somehow couldn't make it work on my html page. Anyone have an idea?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KsUk8/)

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
        var tr = $('#table tbody tr');
        var td = '<td><button>Reserve</button></td>';
        tr.each(function () {
            $(td).insertAfter($(this).find('td').eq(3));
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="15%"><b>Course Code</b>
            </th>
            <th width="25%"><b>Course Description</b>
            </th>
            <th width="35%"><b>Available Schedule</b>
            </th>
            <th width="10%"><b>Reservations</b>
            </th>
            <th width="15%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="output">
        <tr>
            <td>ME101</td>
            <td>Marine Engineering 101</td>
            <td>June 1 - August 30, 2014</td>
            <td>56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ME102</td>
            <td>Marine Engineering 102</td>
            <td>June 1 - August 30, 2014</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ME201</td>
            <td>Marine Engineering 201</td>
            <td>June 1 - August 30, 2014</td>
            <td>54</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ME202</td>
            <td>Marine Engineering 202</td>
            <td>June 1 - August 30, 2014</td>
            <td>47</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CS101</td>
            <td>Certificate in Seamanship 101</td>
            <td>June 1 - August 30, 2014</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

This is the full html structure on the table. Please note that "loadJSP" function to generate the html output of the tbody rows.

```
<div class="col-md-12 well setup-content" id="step-2">
     <h1 class="text-center">STEP 2</h1>

    <p>Select the schedule you wish to attend by clicking the check button on the rightmost column.</p>
    <hr class="colorgraph">
    <form id="reservation2" name="reservation2" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="15%"><b>Course Code</b>
                        </th>
                        <th width="25%"><b>Course Description</b>
                        </th>
                        <th width="35%"><b>Available Schedule</b>
                        </th>
                        <th width="10%"><b>Reservations</b>
                        </th>
                        <th width="15%"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="output">
                    <!-- Data output from JSP will be displayed here. -->
                    <script>
                        loadJSP("pntc_fetchschedules.jsp");
                    </script>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="control-group text-center">
            <button id="activate-step-3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" tabindex="17">Proceed to Step 3</button>
        </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

It finally worked. As suggested by Rajaprabhu, the issue lies with the file `pntc_fetchschedules.jsp`. It seems jquery couldn't see the output of the jsp file. As a fix, I put the jquery script inside `pntc_schedules.jsp` although my intention was to alter the html columns after jsp generated them (that is, without touching the jsp file itself).

If anyone has a better solution according to how I intended it, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you Rajaprabhu for the assistance!

Comment: did you checked console ?????

Comment: No errors on the console.

Comment: which jquery version are you using

Comment: I have jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr = $('#table tbody tr').append('<td><button>Reserve</button></td>');
});` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tWf3j/1/

Comment: @Arun I tried it and it does produce the same result in jsfiddle as mine but won't work in my html page.

Comment: @JNewbie in your dom ready handle add a logging statement like `console.log('dom ready', $('#table tbody tr').length)` - and check your browser console

Comment: @Arun browser console outputs 0. I don't really know what it means. :(

Comment: @JNewbie whether the table contents are loaded dynamically? may be using ajax or created using another script?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correct, you need to insert a new row in the `tbody` with id as `output`

try this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("#output").children().each(function(){
        $(this).append("<tr><td><input type='button' value='Reserve'></input>");
    });
});
```